# Variavel não funciona em uma função em C

Tags: c

Estava fazendo um programa simples em C para eu treinar funções, quando me deparei com um problema que eu não conseguir resolver.

Basicamente, primeiro o meu código pede quantas vezes as funções vão se repetir, depois dentro desse laço pergunta as cinco notas do aluno, coloca em ordem crescente e por fim mostra a média. O meu problema está na função que faz a média, que, pelo o que eu entendi, a variavel não retorna o valor passado e que por fim retorna 0.00

> A media dessas notas sao: 0.00

Queria saber qual seria uma solução para resolver esse problema e, se tiver, sugestões para melhorar o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

float notas[5] = {0};
int x = 0;
int alunos;

printf("De quantos alunos voce quer saber a nota?\n");
scanf("%i", &alunos);
    
while (x<alunos){
    x++;

float pedir_n(float notas[], float a);
pedir_n(notas, 5);

float ordemc(float notas[], float b);
ordemc(notas, 5);

float media(float notas[], float c);
media(notas, 5);
    }
}

float pedir_n(float notas[], float a){ // pede a nota
    int i;
    printf("\nDigite as cinco notas desse(s) aluno(s): \n");
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
    }
}

float ordemc(float notas[], float b){ // colocar em ordem crescente  
    int i,num,num2,troca;
    for (num = 0; num < b; num++){
        for (num2 = num +1; num2 < b; num2++){
            if (notas[num] > notas[num2]){
                troca = notas[num];
                notas[num] = notas[num2];
                notas[num2] = troca;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n---- Numeros em ordem crescente ----\n");
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Nota: %0.2f\n", notas[i]);     
    }printf("---- Numeros em ordem crecente ----\n");
     printf("\n");
}

float media(float notas[], float c){ // FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ A MEDIA 
    int i;
    float med, total;
    med += notas[i];
    total = med / 5;
  printf("A media dessas notas sao: %0.2f\n", total);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esqueceu de percorrer as 5 notas do aluno antes de calcular a média. Uma possível solução seria assim:

```c
float media(float notas[], float c)
{ // FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ A MEDIA
    int i;
    float med, total;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        med += notas[i];
    }
    total = med / 5;
    printf("A media dessas notas sao: %0.2f\n", total);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Sobre as sugestões para melhorar o código seria bom que criasse uma constante para o número de notas de cada aluno, por exemplo no trecho acima você está supondo que sempre serão 5 notas do aluno, mas e se forem 20? Você teria que alterar diversas partes do seu código onde aparece o número 5. Uma maneira de resolver isso seria no começo de seu código definir uma varíavel NUMERO_NOTAS:

```c
#define NUMERO_NOTAS 5
```

Dessa forma na sua função média por exemplo ao invés de alterarmos 2 vezes o código poderíamos apenas substituir o valor da Constante 1 vez, veja:

```c
float media(float notas[], float c)
{ // FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ A MEDIA
    int i;
    float med, total;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMERO_NOTAS; i++){
        med += notas[i];
    }
    total = med / NUMERO_NOTAS;
    printf("A media dessas notas sao: %0.2f\n", total);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, faltava o laço 'for' mesmo. Quanto a sua sugestão, qual a diferença de usar o #define ou, por exemplo, int/float como variavel global?

Comment: A diferença é que os valores declarados com #define não são variáveis no sentido de gastar espaço na memória, o que acontece é que no momento de compilação o pré-processador apenas substitui o nome definido pelo valor. Ou seja, o intuito do #define é apenas substituir valores, já as variáveis globais devem ser usadas caso você queira ler e alterar seu valor de qualquer parte do código.